# How to install mysql-6.0.10-alpha?

Tags: 12.04, mysql-workbench

Currently, I am using Server version: 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu) version of `mysql`. Unfortunately the relational operators aren't working on temporal data types for e.g date.

I see that `mysql-6.0.10-alpha` has already been released: thought the bugs might have been fixed; though couldn't find a way to install it on Ubuntu 12.04.

**Example:-**

```
mysql> select emp_id, fname, lname, start_date,title  from employee ;
+--------+----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
| emp_id | fname    | lname     | start_date | title              |
+--------+----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|      1 | Michael  | Smith     | 2001-06-22 | President          |
|      2 | Susan    | Barker    | 2002-09-12 | Vice President     |
|      3 | Robert   | Tyler     | 2000-02-09 | Treasurer          |
|      4 | Susan    | Hawthorne | 2002-04-24 | Operations Manager |
|      5 | John     | Gooding   | 2003-11-14 | Loan Manager       |
|      6 | Helen    | Fleming   | 2004-03-17 | Head Teller        |
|      7 | Chris    | Tucker    | 2004-09-15 | Teller             |
|      8 | Sarah    | Parker    | 2002-12-02 | Teller             |
|      9 | Jane     | Grossman  | 2002-05-03 | Teller             |
|     10 | Paula    | Roberts   | 2002-07-27 | Head Teller        |
|     11 | Thomas   | Ziegler   | 2000-10-23 | Teller             |
|     12 | Samantha | Jameson   | 2003-01-08 | Teller             |
|     13 | John     | Blake     | 2000-05-11 | Head Teller        |
|     14 | Cindy    | Mason     | 2002-08-09 | Teller             |
|     15 | Frank    | Portman   | 2003-04-01 | Teller             |
|     16 | Theresa  | Markham   | 2001-03-15 | Head Teller        |
|     17 | Beth     | Fowler    | 2002-06-29 | Teller             |
|     18 | Rick     | Tulman    | 2002-12-12 | Teller             |
+--------+----------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select emp_id, fname, lname, start_date,title  from employee where start_date >= '2006-01-01';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Is this an example of relational operator not working? Because I don't see any start date greater than or equals to 2006-01-01.

Comment: I'm sorry, i imported the database from some site; and was running the query as per the book. There  was a mismatch in the date column in the table; which resulted in the incorrect output. I've corrected the dates; the query runs properly now. Anyways thanks for replying; would still like to upgrade to mysql-6.0 on ubuntu 12.04.                                                            Thanks                                                            Ankit

Answer (score 0):

[This(mysql dev download site)](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/6.0.html#downloads) or [this(mirror site)](http://download.softagency.net/MySQL/Downloads/MySQL-6.0/) are the links to download the `mysql-6.0.11-alpha-linux-i686-glibc23.tar.gz` package. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-installation.html) are the installation instructions. Though it's not recommended as it's a pre-release version.

**As the instruction suggests you have to completely remove the version installed with `apt-get` in Ubuntu to make a new installation from source.**

Comment: @Ankit Glad that helped you, you can accept that answer if you think it's appropriate.

Comment: @Ankit You can click the check sign(✓) below the voting area on the left side of an answer [to accept it](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).