# Why automatic installed mysql 5.5 when i install mysql workbench 6.0.9 from deb file using ubuntu software center

Tags: installation, 13.10, software-center, mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and already installed mysql 5.6.16 on it. I have downloaded mysql workbench deb file (mysql-workbench-community-6.0.9-1ubu1310-amd64) from mysql web site.
Now when I run this deb file with Ubuntu Software Center it is automatically install mysql 5.5 in system.

How can I install mysql workbench only??

Thanks in advance

Comment: It installs because of _dependencies_. If you want to install only that package you have downloaded, use command `sudo dpkg -i --force-all package.deb`. This may lead you to erroneous configuration, so be careful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insatll `mysql-workbench-community-6.0.9-1ubu1310-amd64.deb` file without installing `mysql5.5` by running the below command on terminal,

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i  mysql-workbench-community-6.0.9-1ubu1310-amd64.deb
```

The above command will force install the `mysql-workbench.deb` file without installing it's dependencies.

```
 Warning: These options are mostly intended to be used by experts
          only.  Using  them without fully understanding their effects may
          break your whole system.
```

Comment: It is installed but workbench is not running...what should i do to run it properly?

Comment: Now run `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench` and post it's output.

Comment: mysql-workbench : Depends: libctemplate2 but it is not going to be installed

                   AND OTHER DEPENDENCIES....

Comment: Install all the dependencies like `sudo apt-get install libctemplate2`

Comment: ok insatlled All DEPENDENCIES....And when run  mysql --version on terminal it show mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu...Instead of Mysql 5.6.16 AND mysql Server is stopped.Plz let me know the next step to run mysql5.6.16

Comment: What was the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql`?

Comment: libdbd-mysql-perl    install
libmysqlclient18:amd64    install
mysql      install
mysql-client     install
mysql-client-5.5    install
mysql-client-core-5.5    install
mysql-common     install
mysql-workbench-community   install

Comment: but there was no mysql 5.6 installed.It shows only 5.5

Comment: but in   /opt/mysql/server5.6 only. rakesh.javaholic my skype id

Comment: i think you installed mysql client 5.5 and mysql server 5.6

Comment: what should i do to install mysql client 5.6   add me on skype show  that i can show u screen my id- rakesh.javaholic

Comment: sorry i didn't had mysql installed on my pc.See http://askubuntu.com/questions/156182/how-to-install-mysql-6-0-10-alpha